# Resolve service in HttpContext configure Action

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

In asp.net core I am registering typed `HttpClient` and I need resolve service from service provider. How can I resolve services there?

Example:

```
services
    .AddHttpClient<TTypedHttpClient, TTypedHttpClientImpl>(httpClient =>
    {
        // how to resolve service on next line?
        var config = RESOLVE_SERVICE<IConfig>();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = config.GetBaseUrl();
    });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to access configuration in the Startup class's `ConfigureServices` method? Why mention actions and HttpContext?

Comment: No, `IConfig` is meant here as general service that is registered in service provider.

Comment: Those are registered in the ConfigureServices method and have nothing to do with HttpContext or Action.

Comment: Oh, I see. By action I don't mean MVC controller action. I mean the parameter of `AddHttpClient` method. It is the action (anonymous method) that configures the `HttpClient`.

Comment: There's an overload for that but you should probably use config DTOs only instead of service that retrieve settings when a new HttpClient is requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the actual question is how to access configuration or any other service when registering a typed HttpClient and HttpContext (the context of a specific HTTP request) isn't relevant.

**UPDATE** In .NET Core 2.1 AddHttpClient doesn't have an overload with *two* type parameters and a`IServiceCollection` despite what the documentation shows. The same job is performed by caling `ConfigureHttpClient` after AddHttpClient.

```
services
    .AddHttpClient<TTypedHttpClient, TTypedHttpClientImpl>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(svc,httpClient =>
    {
        // how to resolve service on next line?
        var config = svc.GetRequiredService<IConfig>();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = config.GetBaseUrl();
    });
```

**Original**

You can use the [AddHttpClient(IServiceCollection, String, Action< IServiceProvider,HttpClient>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions_AddHttpClient_Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_IServiceCollection_System_String_System_Action_System_IServiceProvider_System_Net_Http_HttpClient__) overload to pass an `IServiceProvider` to the action that can be used to resolve other services :

```
services
    .AddHttpClient<TTypedHttpClient, TTypedHttpClientImpl>((svc,httpClient =>
    {
        // how to resolve service on next line?
        var config = svc.GetRequiredService<IConfig>();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = config.GetBaseUrl();
    });
```

I'd suggest reading Steve Gordon's article series on typed HttpClients and HttpClientFactory. [Using Typed Clients from Singleton Services](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/ihttpclientfactory-patterns-using-typed-clients-from-singleton-services) shows how to use `AddHttpClient` to configure the client. The rest of his articles show how to configure it with HttpClientFactory and Polly for correct pooling and retries

**Configuration**

Steve Gordon's example uses IOption to read the data from the configuration infrastrucure.

```
services.AddHttpClient<IConfigurationService, ConfigurationService>()
.ConfigureHttpClient((serviceProvider, client) =>
{
    var baseAddress = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SdkOptions>>().Value.BaseAddress;
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
});
```

That's a **good** idea - HttpClient registration shouldn't know and shouldn't depend on the souce of its config values. `IConfig` should be nothing more than a configuration DTO loaded in the configuration phase.

.NET Core configuration can load values from json/xml/ini files, databases, external services, environment variables, anything that can return values in `"section:subsection" - value` form. It also allows combining and overloading settings, which can be *very* useful.

I have applications that load settings from files (basic configuration), databases managed by other teams (external service endpoints and credentials) and the command line (possible overrides). The endpoint configurations are used to create N named HttpClients, one per endpoint. I've used [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#custom-configuration-provider) to create an EF Core provider that loads the endpoint settings.

This allows validation of the settings when the application starts too, which can be a significant benefit. Without it, the application wouldn't know something's wrong until the first time a specific HttpClient was requested.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the overload (first part of your answer), but even though it is in documentation for .NET Core 2.1 it's not there in code (https://github.com/aspnet/HttpClientFactory/blob/release/2.1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Http/DependencyInjection/HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions.cs). It is already in .NET Core 2.2 release branch, but that is in preview right now.

The `ConfigureHttpClient` extension is in .NET Core 2.1 so I can use that.

Comment: @MartinVolek it has an overload that accepts a single type parameter but not two

Comment: Yes, now I know. And the single parameter overload is insufficient for my purpose (that is why I have posted the question).